# Breaking a pair tie

Tags: rules

Let's say two players have the following hands:

- Player A: 2♦️, 2♣️
- Player B: 2♠️, 2♥️

How would this play out? Is it a split pot?

I'm a noob trying to wrap my head around some of the rules. As I understand it, a "kicker" is normally used to break a pair tie, and the kicker is any card not used in the hand. However, in this example, the kickers would have to come from the community cards, so they would be identical and the tie would remain.

Would you use the value of the suits instead, like ♠️ > ♥️ > ♦️ > ♣️

Or is it simply a split pot?

Comment: It's worth noting that kickers are part of your hand too. A hand is always five cards. If you have 88 and your opponent has QJ and the board is 8AAAA, then your opponents best hand is AAAAQ which beats your best hand (AAAA8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a split pot in every case except when one player makes a flush. Because they have different suits, it is possible for the board to come out like J♦️ 3♦️ T♦️ 6♦️ 5♣ for player A to make a flush and win. Suit rankings are not used in determining the strength of a hand in poker.